# Como selecionar opções de um select populado dinamicamente pelo vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho um select num formulário, e os itens desse select é populado dinamicamente pelo vue.js.

O meu problema é que quando eu abrir um cadastro salvo no banco de dados para edição neste formulário, eu preciso fazer com que alguns itens seja selecionado de acordo com o que foi salvo antes, e não sei como fazer isto.

Se alguém conhecer outra biblioteca parecida com vue.js que seja tão leve quanto e mais fácil de usar, eu tbm aceito sugestões ♥.

Segue o meu código:

```js
var setores = new Vue({
  el: '#v-for-negociossetores',
  data: {
     setoresitens: {"countcats":16,"countsubcats":56,"catsubcatsdata":{"123":{"titulo":"Alimentos","descricao":"Padarias, Mercados, Restaurantes, Lanchonetes e etc.","subcats":{"345":{"codurl":"restaurantes","titulo":"Restaurantes","descricao":""}}},"abc":{"titulo":"Religiões","descricao":"","subcats":{"def":{"codurl":"igrejas","titulo":"Igrejas","descricao":""},"ghi":{"codurl":"religiao-casas","titulo":"Casas","descricao":""},"jkl":{"codurl":"religiao-templos","titulo":"Templos","descricao":""},"mno":{"codurl":"religiao-terreiros","titulo":"Terreiros","descricao":""}}}}}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

 <div class="row clearfix">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="form-group" id="v-for-negociossetores">
  <select name="codsetores[]" class="form-control show-tick" multiple title="Setores">
      <optgroup v-for="(group, keygroup) in setoresitens.catsubcatsdata" v-bind:label="group.titulo">
          <option v-for="(option, keyoption) in group.subcats" v-bind:value="keyoption">
            {{ option.titulo }}
            </option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Nossa Samantha, ficou bem confuso essa sua pergunta. Se entendi o que você quer é popular o select com os dados do Banco é isto?

Comment: Use conforme o exemplo do manual (segundo exemplo para selects): https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Comment: @LeAndrade desculpa, eu não sei como explicar melhor na pergunta. Mas não é isso não, popular o select eu ja consigo que é o que esta na pergunta. Mas a população do select vem de um arquivo em json. O q preciso é quando abrir um registro cadastrado no banco de dados, que além de popular o select como eu ja faço, que ele ja deixe selecionado os itens que foram salvos anteriormente.  Não sei se to conseguindo explicar direito.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu olhei a documentação, foi assim que eu consegui chegar até onde eu postei. Mas ainda não sei como deixar alguns itens selecionados. Não vi nenhum exemplo parecido na documentação, ou pelo menos não entendi caso tenha algo falando sobre isso lá. Você pode me ajudar com alguma explicação mais prática? por favor

Comment: Precisa de um atributo `v-model=seumodelo` na tag select. E no seu objeto `data`, um `seumodelo: valor_selecionado`. Acho que é só isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto ahh ok, vou tentar entender mais sobre o atributo v-model, obrigado pela explicação, vou tentar aqui e jaja eu falo se deu certo, obrigada.

Comment: @bfavaretto ahh deu certo, é isso mesmo, obrigadaaa. Quer fazer uma resposta mais detalhada para que eu escolha sua resposta?? Ou eu mesma respondo e te menciono na resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois das seguintes respostas do **@bfavaretto**:

> Use conforme o exemplo do manual (segundo exemplo para selects):
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select
>
> Precisa de um atributo **v-model=seumodelo** na tag **select**.
>
> E no seu objeto **data**, um **seumodelo: valor_selecionado**.

E pela documentação do **Vue.js**:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>

new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
      { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
      { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
    ]
  }
})
```

Eu consegui resolver meu problema e ficou da seguinte forma no caso de multiple selects:

```js
var setores = new Vue({
  el: '#v-for-negociossetores',
  data: {
     setoresselecionados: ["ghi", "mno"],
     setoresitens: {"countcats":16,"countsubcats":56,"catsubcatsdata":{"123":{"titulo":"Alimentos","descricao":"Padarias, Mercados, Restaurantes, Lanchonetes e etc.","subcats":{"345":{"codurl":"restaurantes","titulo":"Restaurantes","descricao":""}}},"abc":{"titulo":"Religiões","descricao":"","subcats":{"def":{"codurl":"igrejas","titulo":"Igrejas","descricao":""},"ghi":{"codurl":"religiao-casas","titulo":"Casas","descricao":""},"jkl":{"codurl":"religiao-templos","titulo":"Templos","descricao":""},"mno":{"codurl":"religiao-terreiros","titulo":"Terreiros","descricao":""}}}}}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

 <div class="row clearfix">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="form-group" id="v-for-negociossetores">
  <select name="codsetores[]" class="form-control show-tick" multiple title="Setores" v-model="setoresselecionados">
      <optgroup v-for="(group, keygroup) in setoresitens.catsubcatsdata" v-bind:label="group.titulo">
          <option v-for="(option, keyoption) in group.subcats" v-bind:value="keyoption">
            {{ option.titulo }}
            </option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Só para fins de deixar registrado aqui no site para consultas em futuras questões. Conforme o **@bfavaretto** mencionou é só colocar o `v-model` no select e na propriedade `data` setar os elementos que se quer selecionar:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: ['A','B']
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected" multiple>
    <option disabled value="">Selecione</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
  <span>Selecionados: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigada por responder moço. A resposta do @bfavaretto ja tinha me ajudado. Eu vou só colocar a minha resposta como correta, pq vou dar mais detalhes de acordo com o meu caso. Mas obrigada por deixar a resposta dele registrada na pergunta. ^^